# Pandas: How to label groupby data in plot?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to plot a graph of the following data:
[image]

When I use `df.groupby('Item').sum().plot()` it results:

[image]

First, it does not seem to show all 107 records, 2nd, I don't know how to label Item names on X-axis. Any pointer pls?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Images do not help!

Comment: A line plot is *not* the right way to display this data, there is no linear correlation between the items.  Use a bar chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a line chart here, use a bar chart, as there is no linear correlation between any of your items. This will solve your labeling problem at the same time:

```
df.groupby('Item').sum().plot(kind='bar')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!